# Why does Laravel instantiates a class to get a property instead of setting this property as static?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Eloquent\Model class has a protected property named ***table***. In order to get this property's value Laravel creates a new instance of the parent class, and then gets the value:

```
(new static)->table
```

Why not just set the property as static? And then:

```
MyModel::$table
```

or

```
static::$table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason is that static variable is same for all dervied models so it would be difficult to track table name for derived type.

```
class Base
{
    public static $table;
}

class Derived1 extends Base { }
class Derived2 extends Base { }

Base::$table = "Table";

echo Derived1::$table;
echo Derived2::$table;
```

Here, both derived classes will have same table name.

Also, **new static()** will create an instance of class that method was called on.

```
class Base
{
    public $table;

    public static function create($table)
    {
        // Create instace of derived class
        $instance = new static();
        $instance->table = $table;
        return $instance;
    }
}

class Derived1 extends Base { }
class Derived2 extends Base { }

print_r(Derived1::create("Table1"));  
print_r(Derived2::create("Table2"));
```

In this case, each instance will have own table property and even factory method was in base class instance will be of type that was called on.

*Update*
If you would like to use static variable in base class and still be able to have different values then you would use map where class name is a key.

```php
class Base
{
    private static $table;

    public static function create($table)
    {
        $instance = new static();
        self::$table[get_class($instance)] = $table;
        return $instance;
    }

    public function getTableName()
    {
        return self::$table[get_class($this)];
    }
}

class Derived1 extends Base { }
class Derived2 extends Base { }

$d1 = Derived1::create("Table1");
$d2 = Derived2::create("Table2");

echo $d1->getTableName(); //prints Table1
echo $d2->getTableName(); //prints Table2
```